# Why my jetstream application in Laravel not showing proper CSS and JS path when uploading in Cpanel?

Tags: laravel

I have built a project in laravel using jetstream. The project is running smoothly in my local machine (localhost) but the CSS and JS path is not working when I am uploading in server. Can anyone help?

[image]

My cpanel directory is

```
public_html/pro1/admin/
```

### Error

```
Falied to load resource : app.js
Falied to load resource : app.css
Falied to load resource : app.css
```

Comment: what is the error code?
is it a 404

Comment: Yes it is 404 error

Comment: can you add the code where you want to load the scripts

Comment: Now I am getting another error.
Access denied for user @'localhost' (using password: NO ). I do not know what is happening.

Comment: try this in your cmd: mysql -u root -p
if that not works. follow this:  https://www.educative.io/answers/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

The above links are not working in cpanel

Comment: why did you use mix?
try asset() instead of mix()